# Yii2 autocomplete chain of methods in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, yii, yii2

In netbeans I already installed yii2 plugin, my query was how to make autocomplete for method chaining too. Because here in the below code

```
$query = Message::find()->orderBy('name')->
```

After the second object operator (`->`) autocomplete not working.

So How we can achieve autocomplete for chain of methods in netbeans with yii2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can without changing the Yii framework code (not recommended).

Autocomplete does not work properly on the `orderBy()` method, most likely because it's using phpdoc @return $this. 
Seems NetBeans prefers the use of the keyword `this` instead of `$this` (Also see: [NetBeans bug#239987](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=239987)) but changing it in the framework code didn't work for me either. It worked when I changed it to `static` though.

This might also be related to [NetBeans bug#196565](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196565)

Alternatively you could use inline type hinting:

```
$query = Message::find()->orderBy('name');
/* @var $query \yii\db\ActiveQuery */
```

but I usually just grab the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) to prevent cluttering up the code. (Having 2 monitors helps)

Comment: why you used `ActiveQuery` class instead of `ActiveRecord` and also How this solution works in method chaining like `->offset()->limit()->al()`?

Comment: Because ActiveRecord::find() returns an ActiveQuery object, not an instance of itself (That's Yii 1.x behavior). Auto complete for method chaining (i see it now) will not really work, because all those methods are using phpdoc with `@return $this`, so grabbing the docs or memorising some of those methods is probably your best option.